# Getting one Python program to "feed" another one

Tags: python, io

I am trying to do some work on 2-SAT and 3-SAT for an assignment and I was allowed to search the web for the implementation of the program. I came across 2 programs in Python that basically I can run and they enable me to continue with my assignment. However I can't get the output from one program to feed the other one:

The code here: http://goo.gl/6fdlq should provide input for the code here: http://goo.gl/rdfyR
which is what the instructions say:

> Problem generator in Python -
>   Generates either C syntax expressions
>   or the input to... Fully functional
>   GSAT solver in Python - takes input
>   from the above and attempts to satisfy
>   it, while generating a log of the
>   output intended to be instructional to
>   those unfamiliar with the GSAT
>   algorithm.

Anyone could please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is pipe the output from the first script into the second.

Since the scripts seem to be named `3sat.py` and `gsat.py` respectively, just `cd` into the directory where they're located and run:

```
./3sat.py | ./gsat.py
```

or, equivalently:

```
python 3sat.py | python gsat.py
```